# SyntaxError: The requested module '@notionhq/client' does not provide an export named 'Client'

Tags: notion-api

I'm following Notion's instructions to use the Notion API. From the terminal, I have installed the client library ("npm install"). The problem is when I run the script ("node index.js") I get the following error message:

```
import { Client } from "@notionhq/client"
         ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: The requested module '@notionhq/client' does not provide an export named 'Client'
```

And for reference my package.json file looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "notion-example",
    "type": "module",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "dependencies": {
        "@notionhq/client": "^0.1.9"
    }
}
```

Can someone help me to understand how to resolve this error? I'm still fairly new to coding so any feedback would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Everything looks right. Since version 0.4.4 is out, you might want to try updating your package.

Here's the command to update the package:

```sh
npm update @notionhq/client
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem which I got around using:

```
const { Client } = require("@notionhq/client")
```